# Prevent multiple registrations from the same email using + character

Tags: 7, users, emails

Gmail and other email services allow users to extend their address using the + (plus) character.

For example, mail to

> spamme@gmail.com
>
> spamme+sideways@gmail.com
>
> spamme+tomorrow@gmail.com

will all be receivable by the owner of `spamme@gmail.com`

In its default configuration, Drupal 7 would allow the owner of `spamme@gmail.com` to register 3 separate accounts using the 3 addresses above... and more if they want!

I would like to prevent this type of multiple registration.

While I could just create a rule that blacklists email addresses containing the `+` character, [there are legitimate uses of this](https://www.drupal.org/node/2157963).

I would prefer to be able to check for other equivalent email addresses, where in the above example, all 3 addresses are equivalent, because they are all collectable by `spamme@gmail.com`, and allow only one of them.

Is there some way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Create a second field for users that stores only real email address (everything before the +).

then use a user registration preprocess hook to check if that exists already with a simple database query.

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_presave/7.x

Comment: Why use an additional field and presave hook? I think this is not the correct way. Better alter your registration form and add a custom validator where you check if the email without the +xxx already exists. This way you can easily raise an error correctly.

Comment: @schlicki because it still leaves the user with their preferred address. sometimes a user is not malicious and just wants to be able to track/filter using a +xxx.  better to keep the user's choice, and solve the multiple registration problem separately, in my opinion.

Comment: I like the concept of keeping both addresses here - as you mentioned, it's better to be able to contact the user with their preferred address, even if it contains a +, but then performing validation operations on the clean version of the address. But I don't want to ask the user to enter it twice! How would you copy and clean the email into a separate field?

Answer (score 1):

Check email before register user with add your custom validator in hook_form_alter, then check user email without `+secondpart` :

As a Example you can Try something like this (**I didn't test this but it can give you a good clue to achieve what you want** )

```
 function YOURMODULENAME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
       if ($form_id == "user_register_form") {
            // add your custom validator
            $form['#validate'][] = 'my_custom_email_validate';
       }
     }
```

in your custom validator check it with regular expression

```
function my_custom_email_validate($form, $form_state, $form_id){
    // dpm($form_state['values']);
    $mail = $form_state['values']['mail'];
    preg_match_all('/(.*)\+.*(@.*)/',$mail,$matches);
if($matches){
    // this mean it has  xxx+xx@xxx pattern
    $clean_mail = $matches[1][0].$matches[2][0];
    $user_load = user_load_by_mail($clean_mail);
    if($user_load){
        form_set_error('mail',t('Sorry,This email used before.don\'t waste your time dear spammer'));
        return false;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or for modern Drupal versions, see this module to prevent duplicate registration:

https://www.drupal.org/project/unwanted_email_registration

Answer (score 0):

I actually found a module that solves this problem already: [Duplemail](https://www.drupal.org/project/duplemail).

This doesn't actually answer my problem just yet, because I found it's incompatible with [LoginToboggan](https://www.drupal.org/project/logintoboggan), which seems to bypass the validate method that Duplemail hooks onto. Since LoginToboggan is already deployed...

So... I'm going to try [Email Registration](https://www.drupal.org/project/email_registration) and Duplemail to see if this solves the issue